# How to handle PayPal IPN after changing domain?

Tags: php, paypal

What will be a standard procedure in the case where you have an application that have  paypal monthly subscriptions and IPN message sent every month to an IPN receiver URL.

We set `ipn_url` in the registration form when users sign up.

**For example**

I have a domain `http://domain.com/ipn.php` where I receive all IPN. Now my site moves to `http://example.com/ipn.php`. Note that, I have  `http://domain.com/ipn.php` saved in PayPal account as IPN URL.

Comment: Can't you change that setting in your PayPal account? I would contact PayPal about this. If they can't do anything, consider using a 301 redirect.

Comment: 301 redirect will remove all POST data.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13628908/2624391) answer for preserving POST data. I'm not sure that would work, however, as I recall that your listener has to send a "200 OK" response to PayPal. Do you still have access to the old domain? Why not just keep your IPN listener there? That's the only solution I can think of. Perhaps contact PayPal?

Comment: @Tim: We haven't changed the domain yet. Need a solution before we create the problem right? ;) I have see some IPN broadcaster script which send POST request using CURL. I think I may go into that route if there is no other way.

Comment: Yeah, if your going to have access to the old domain, as far as I know, the only solution is to have some type of script there to handle the incoming IPNs.

Comment: I guess, we will have to keep the domain, its the easier way out it seems.

Comment: That's really unfortunate, have you talked to a rep to see if subscriber IPN URL will default to the one in the account settings?

Comment: I use this service: https://ipnforwarder.com/ so then I can change the notify url when ever i want (and also can send the ipn to multiple urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454900/change-the-ipn-url-on-existing-subscription) on SO appears to be what you're looking for. There are conflicting answers on the post, but it appears that if you set the URL for your IPN listener at the code level i.e. in your PayPal form you defined `notify_url`, then there is no way of updating this.

From the top answer on the aforementioned post:

> I had exactly the same problem .... I had to move servers which meant my IPN url changed. I have spoken to 3 different paypal reps and even had a meeting with a tech support guy from there.
>
> Unfortunately, there is NO WAY to change the IPN url for existing customers/subscriptions.
>
> I have been advised that all existing customers/subscriptions would need to be setup again, your customers would then need to start a new subscription based on the new IPN url. This is a right PITA ... I have just over 1500 customers I need to do this for, and I can guarantee I will lose some due to the hassle of this.
>
> Sorry this wasn't the answer you were looking for :(

If it's viable, I would leave the IPN listener where it is.

However, the answer above *is* a few years old and there might be a solution I'm not aware of. Perhaps you could contact customer support.