# Changing PayPal IPN for subscriptions

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm doing a design for a company and we've ran into a slight issue regarding PayPal IPN. It seems from what i've read up **if I change the PayPal IPN listener it will still send future payments to that old IPN**

[Change the IPN url on existing subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454900/change-the-ipn-url-on-existing-subscription)

We could setup a 307 redirect but the company does not own the domain of where their current IPN listener is located.

Is there any way we can manually transfer the subscriptions to receive new information regarding past subscriptions or will subscriptions have to be cancelled/restarted by the user.

Comment: I use this service: https://ipnforwarder.com/ so then I can change the notify url when ever i want (and also can send the ipn to multiple urls)

Answer (score 0):

If the IPNs are being sent to a domain you no longer have control of then you'll need to kill the profiles and have them re-created.  If you did have access to the old domain then you could setup a simple listener there that forwards the IPN data to your new listener.